# Migrate data from dynamics crm to salesforce

Tags: salesforce, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to know some best practice for migrating data from microsoft crm to salesforce crm.

Should you use migration tools?
If so what good migration tools are there out there?

Should I migrate it the data first to microsoft excel and then migration it from excel to salesforce?

I read that you can import data to salesforce crm by .csv files. Can you for example export data från dynamics crm to .csv files and then import the files with salesforce. Is this an alternativ solution?

What practice leaves you with less functionality loss?

Answer (score 1):

I just recently went through an evaluation of the tools available and found that [Scribe Insight](http://www.scribesoft.com/) is still the best tool for connecting to Dynamics CRM.  Their 60-day license option is great for one-time data migrations.

Comment: What other tools did you evaluate?

Comment: I looked at [Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/) and [Pervasive](http://www.pervasive.com/).  I didn't consider [Informatica](http://www.informatica.com/us/company/news-and-events-calendar/press-releases/03192012-microsoft-dynamics-crm-cloud.aspx) because their price was too high for my implementation